# work with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 query in php and I want to put and execute query1 before query2 , query1 is a select query and query2 is a delete query.when I put query2 before query1 in php code both queries work properly but when I put query1 before query2 only query1 works,and query2 not works.

query1:

```
$result = mysql_query( 'CALL view_polls('.$blogId.');' );
```

query2:

```
 $rlt=mysql_query('CALL delete_poll('.$I.');');
```

All code :

```
$blogId=1;  
    $r=$_GET['rowNumber'];

$result = mysql_query( 'CALL view_polls('.$blogId.');' );

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
for($i=0;$i<$r;$i++)
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
//echo $row['id'];
$I=$row['id'];
$rlt=mysql_query('CALL delete_poll(.'$I.');');  `
```

my procedures are simple select and delete procedure.

view_poll proc :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prj`.`view_polls` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `view_polls`(IN b_id INT)
BEGIN
select id,title,showPoll,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5,ans6 from poll
where blog_id=b_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

delete_poll proc :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prj`.`delete_poll` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_poll`(IN I int)
BEGIN
   delete from poll
   where id=I;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?  What errors do you get?  What do the procedures themselves look like?  What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: Where does `$r` come from?  What is the point of the `for` loop?  Its very unclear what you're trying to accomplish or even what exactly is not working.

Comment: $r come from a post form, it is correct, you can use $r=2;the end line of code is not working

Comment: When you say that the last line of code isn't working, you mean that it doesn't delete what you expect it to delete.  So, what do you expect it to delete?  What is contained in `$I` at the end?  Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your code.

Comment: Also, what is the code for the procedures `view_polls()` and `delete_poll()`?

Comment: I post code of procedures in my question,I have add error_reporting(E_ALL); but I dont get any error

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know where `$r` comes from, but the most likely problem is that you have reached the end of the first result set so `$row` is false and `$I` is not an ID.

Comment: No,I print $I, and it is an ID

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to solve your problem. Can you post the code for SQL view_polls and delete_poll? Also two more things I want to point out:

1) Be sure to use mysql_real_escape_string on $blogId to prevent SQL injection attacks. 
2) It seems like you are treating $row as an associative array. You don't need to use mysql_fetch_array, instead you can use mysql_fetch_assoc which doesn't also return the numerical indexes the first does.

Maybe it's possible that there is a problem in view_poll() and it will only work correctly when there are no polls to view (which happens when you call delete_poll())

Comment: Alright, I took a look at your procedure code. They look fine, nothing seems to be wrong with them. From what I can tell, this is not an SQL error. It is a logic error. I think it is on these lines:

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
for($i=0;$i<$r;$i++)
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

First you call view_row which is a SELECT query that stores the result set in $row. But then you loop through it and call mysql_fetch_array again, which is wrong. $row is not a MySQL resource, it is an Array. Try doing a var_dump() or print_r() and see what you get.

Comment: I dont think,because when I change code in this shap,it dosnt work too : `$result = mysql_query( 'CALL view_polls('.$blogId.');' );
$rlt=mysql_query('CALL delete_poll(2);');
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
for($i=0;$i<$r;$i++)
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$I=$row['id']; `